# How to set traversal order by ENTER in SWT

Tags: java, swt

In SWT, we can set the tab oder by using the code below:

```
composite.setTabList(new Control[]{button1, button3});
```

Is there any way to change the key traversal from Tab to <kbd>Enter</kbd>? My application connect to a bar code reader and it just support <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after read the barcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `TraverseListener` in SWT that can be used to change the effect of traversal keys.

For example, a traverse listener can be used to focus the next field on <kbd>Enter</kbd> like this:

```
text.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
  @Override
  public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent event) {
    if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
      event.doit = false;
      // focus next control
    }
  }
});
```

Setting the `doit` flag of the event to `false` consumes the event and prevents it from causing the default action - if any. In a multi-line text field, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key may begin a new line unless the event was consumed by a listener.

Comment: It's been two years but could you elaborate if you solved this in the end and if yes how? I'm looking for a way to globally do this in my RCP application (not on a per component basis) but so far, no dice.

Comment: My first would attempt would be a display listener (`Display::addListener`) that filters traverse events (`event.type == SWT.Traverse`) and then does the same as the listener from the answer. Be mindful that changing the keyboard navigation behavior of an entire application is drastic measure.

Comment: Luckily I'm not changing the keyboard navigation but I'm doing a reimplementation of an existing product that already uses said navigation. See my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165078/focus-switch-using-enter-in-swt-eclipse-rcp-applikation if you want to join the discussion there.