# Focus Switch using ENTER in SWT/Eclipse RCP Applikation

Tags: java, swing, swt, eclipse-rcp

In Swing/AWT it is possible to extends the DefaultKeyboardFocusManager to do something like this:

```
HashSet<KeyStroke> forwardSet = new HashSet<KeyStroke>();
forwardSet.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false));
forwardSet.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0, false));
setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.unmodifiableSet(forwardSet));
```

By overriding

```
@Override
public void processKeyEvent(Component focusedComponent, KeyEvent e)
```

extending DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy and some glue code it was possible to switch focus using ENTER everywhere within the application.

I would need to do the same in a newly developed SWT/Eclipse RCP application but so far I have found no way to implement this.
Any pointers on how this could be achieved?

Some clarification:
Im looking for a global solution, not on a per control basis.
I looked into using a Traverse Listener and, from there, creating a FocusChange but I couldn't find a way to do that either and it would have to be on a per control basis.
I also looked into a key_down eventlistener approach on `Display`, but couldn't find a way to globally initiate a focus switch from there. My application only needs to run on Windows.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I don't know anything about Swing so telling me how you do it in Swing doesn't help. Since SWT uses the native controls keyboard focus is largely done by the native code.

Comment: As described above I want to be able to switch focus not only using TAB but also using ENTER. This should work throughout the application.

Comment: You might be able to do something with Traverse listeners, but they would have to be on all controls. Or possible a key down filter on the `Display`. Note: on macOS the Tab key can be configured to work in two ways, the default doesn't focus on every control - duplicating that would require mac specific code.

Comment: Currently I'm looking for a global solution, not a per control solution. Besides, I looked into using a Traverse Listener and, from there, creating a FocusChange but I couldn't find a way to do that either.
I like your key_down filter approach on Display, tried that, too, but how to (globally!) initiate a focus switch from there?
It only needs to run on Windows, I'll add that information to the original question, thanks for this input!